# Non-active users and swap

Tags: swap, user-space

I use ubuntu 14.04 and I have a question about swap utilization with respect to having multiple users logged into xwindows. Specifically I have two users that use this computer and it seems that the computer takes a hit when both are logged in (one user account is logged into xwindows but inactive and the other user is logged in and active).

My question is this: does ubuntu take the memory used by the inactive user and place it into swap? If not is there a way to make this happen? Additionally what can I do to reduce the load on the computer incurred from the inactive users?

Thanks